# How do I remove the big play button at the end of a video playing (VideoJS)

Tags: javascript, html, video, html5-video, video.js

I posted this in the VideoJS forums but have yet to receive a response, I was hoping I could get some assistance here. : )

I am trying to remove the "big play button" that shows up once a video is finished playing in video js.

I have tried numerous hides/shows but can't seem to get it to disappear at the end. I've gotten it to hide at the beginning by simply altering the css, but I've found nothing for the end. I am using the most current release of Video JS, and therefore the old fixes that I have found do not work.

Please help. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 5):

The CSS answer is best, though you might be better hiding it in your own stylesheet so you can upgrade to later versions of Video.js without issue. This should do it.

```
.video-js.vjs-default-skin .vjs-big-play-button { display: none; }
```

You could also remove the line that includes the bigPlayButton component, but that would really prevent easy upgrading.

https://github.com/zencoder/video-js/blob/master/src/core.js#L69

Answer (score 1):

Just remove/alter the CSS, it's in there.
It's line 328 until 360 in video-js.css

https://github.com/zencoder/video-js/blob/master/design/video-js.css

Comment: The link you provided is not available.

Answer (score 0):

Their javascript adds a class on the id to indicate the video has finished playing. Add the following css line:

```
.vjs-paused .vjs-big-play-button { display: none; }
```